# SQLiteException: near "" syntax error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

My SQLiteOpenHelper class:

```
public class MyUsersDatabaseAdapter
{
    MyUsersDatabase myUsersDatabase;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

public MyUsersDatabaseAdapter(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version)
{
    myUsersDatabase = new MyUsersDatabase(context, name, factory, version);
}

public long inserDataToDatabase(String firstName,String lastName)
{
    sqLiteDatabase = myUsersDatabase.getWritableDatabase(); // sqliteDatabase is a reference to my database

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(MyUsersDatabase.FIRST_NAME,firstName ); // First parameter(key) is the name of the column
    contentValues.put(MyUsersDatabase.LAST_NAME, lastName);

    long id = sqLiteDatabase.insert(MyUsersDatabase.TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    return id;
}

static class MyUsersDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "usersDatabase";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "usersTable";
    private static final String UID = "_id"; // User identification number
    private static final String FIRST_NAME = "First Name"; // Column
    private static final String LAST_NAME = "Last Name"; // Column
    private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MyUsersDatabase.DATABASE_NAME + "(" 
    + UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    + FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, " 
    + LAST_NAME + " TEXT);";
    private static final String DROP_TABLE = "DROP TBALE IF EXIST " + TABLE_NAME;

    private Context context;


    public MyUsersDatabase(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,int version)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        this.context = context;
        ToastMessage.message(context, "Constructor was called");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        ToastMessage.message(context, "onCreate() was called");
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
        }
        catch (SQLException e)
        {
            ToastMessage.message(context,"" + e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {
        ToastMessage.message(context, "onUpgrade() was called");
        try
        {
            db.execSQL(DROP_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        } 
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            ToastMessage.message(context,"" + e);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat:

```
09-14 16:50:13.711: E/SQLiteLog(26257): (1) near "Name": syntax error
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257): Error inserting Last Name= First Name=
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "Name": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO usersTable(Last Name,First Name) VALUES (?,?)
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:894)
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:505)
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
09-14 16:50:13.713: E/SQLiteDatabase(26257):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1570)
```

So i fet this `LogCat` after clicking a `Button`.

Main class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    viewsInitialization();

    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

    myUsersDatabase = new MyUsersDatabaseAdapter(SignUpActivity.this,"UsersDatabase" , null, 1);
contentValues = new ContentValues();

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            userFirstName = firstNameEditText.getText().toString();
            userLastName = lastNameEditText.getText().toString();

            id = myUsersDatabase.inserDataToDatabase(userFirstName, userLastName);
            if (id < 0)
            {
                ToastMessage.message(SignUpActivity.this, "Unsuccessful row insertion");
            }
            else 
            {
                ToastMessage.message(SignUpActivity.this, "Successful row insertion");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And also the `Toast` "Unsuccessful row insertion".

So whats wrong with my code?

**EDIT**

After removing blanks from column names i get this LogCat:

```
9-14 17:17:04.049: E/SQLiteLog(32247): (1) table usersTable has no column named LastName
09-14 17:17:04.051: E/SQLiteDatabase(32247): Error inserting LastName=hsh FirstName=hshsh
09-14 17:17:04.051: E/SQLiteDatabase(32247): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table usersTable has no column named LastName (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO usersTable(LastName,FirstName) VALUES (?,?)
09-14 17:17:04.051: E/SQLiteDatabase(32247):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-14 17:17:04.051: E/SQLiteDatabase(32247):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:894)
```

Comment: remove whitespace from the column names

Comment: `DROP TBALE`? Isn't that what farmers in Yorkshire do when they trip over? (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_article_reduction)

Comment: @AndyTurner Didn't understand the joke :)

Comment: @God whether or not you get the joke, hopefully you get that `TBALE` is not a keyword in SQL.

Comment: @AndyTurner Changed that. Still the same problem..

Answer (score 3):

You should not use blank in tables names. If you what do do so, you have to use backticks around the names.
Better solution is to rename the columns without using blanks.

Comment: Where are the blanks? in the `TABLE_NAME` and `FIRST_NAME` etc? or in the CREATE TABLE?

Comment: @God "First Name and "Last Name". That are the values for your column names.

Comment: `LAST_NAME = "Last Name"`.   `FIRST_NAME = "First Name";`see the blank space? Also there is a typo found by @Andy Turner

Comment: I changed it to a one word in both and i get a different LogCat which i will post.

Comment: @God It can not be. please clean, rebuild and rerun your app.

Comment: @God Looks like your create method will not executed.

Comment: @God Clear the app data or uninstall and reinstall so that it creates the database again with the new names.

Comment: How do i clear the app data or uniinstall it please?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your table has columns with spaces in them, and the column names are not wrapped in tick characters (`). You can solve this problem one of two ways:

**1st way (Recommended)**

Rename your table columns from "First Name" and "Last Name" to "FirstName" and "LastName" (note the removed space). After doing this, you will need to trigger a call to `onUpgrade` so your upgrade code is ran (in your case, it will drop the old table so the new table can be created). Afterwards, your column names will match, there will be no whitespace characters, and your database should work great.

After making this change, your old database will still be in tact and needs to be updated with the new columns.  You can either delete the old column, or use the `onUpgrade` feature of `SQLiteOpenHelper` as mentioned in the previous paragraph.

**2nd way** *(not as good) but including for completeness*

Add ticks around your code:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + MyUsersDatabase.DATABASE_NAME + "(" 
+ UID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
+ "`" + FIRST_NAME + "` TEXT, " 
+ "`" + LAST_NAME + "` TEXT);";
```

This works, but including whitespace characters in column names is generally considered to be bad practice.

*Final thought*

You can add ticks around the column names either way, since the ticks just define that what is wrapped inside is a single object and should be parsed together. Also, column names with spaces in them are bad practice, you should never include spaces in table names (even though it is possible).

Comment: I did the first thing. Check mt  EDIT post.

Comment: The updated LogCat you posted says `table usersTable has no column named LastName` which means that LastName column does not exist in the table. Did you forget to rename the column from "Last Name" to "LastName" ?

Comment: no. `private static final String FIRST_NAME = "FirstName"; // Column
  private static final String LAST_NAME = "LastName"; // Column`

Comment: The old table needs to be dropped since it created in your previous code. Since you made a change to the database structure, you need to drop the old table and recreate the new one. Based on your code, it looks like you should be able to do this by calling the `onUpgrade` command somehow -- probably by incrementing `DATABASE_VERSION` to 5.

Comment: Still the same `LogCat`. like exactly the same. after i updated the VERSION

Comment: What is the exception? It's likely that we're one step closer.

Comment: Its the same LagCat from the edit. still SQLiteException.

Comment: Thanks for the help bro. But you are leaving me with the problem?